# FOR JSON in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Is there any way i can return JSON data in given below format using FOR JSON in SQL Server 2016?

```
 { 
     "draw": 1, 
     "recordsTotal": 57, 
     "recordsFiltered": 57, 
     "data": 
     [ 
         {
         "first_name": "Airi", 
         "last_name": "Satou", 
         "position": "Accountant",
         "office": "Tokyo", 
         "start_date": "28th Nov 08", 
         "salary": "$162,700" 
         } 
     ]
 }
```

Tried the following query. But not getting the desired output -

```
SELECT
    1 AS draw
    ,100 AS recordsTotal
    ,10 AS recordsFiltered
,(SELECT 
    first_name
    ,last_name
    ,position
    ,office
    ,start_date
    ,salary
FROM Employees
FOR JSON PATH,ROOT('Employees'),INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)
```

The query given below is giving the output properly but not able to append columns "draw", "recordsFiltered" and "totalRows" in to the JSON -

```
SELECT 
        first_name
        ,last_name
        ,position
        ,office
        ,start_date
        ,salary
    FROM Employees
    FOR JSON PATH,ROOT('Employees'),INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
```

Comment: Sample data is going to be useful here. The query and expected output are good, but we don't know what your data looks like, so getting from A->B is hard, when we don't know what A is.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match your data at all -- "product" fields don't match up with what looks like person records. Specify exact input and output. For starters, though, it looks like your outer query is missing the `FOR JSON` clause that would put `draw`, `recordsTotal` and `recordsFiltered` in the end result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be quite the same with `sys.objects` as dummy table source (Btw: Always try to create a working *stand-alone* example, either by providing a table with some data or by using some general system table everybody can use)

```
SELECT
     1 AS draw
    ,100 AS recordsTotal
    ,10 AS recordsFiltered
,(
    SELECT TOP 3
     o.object_id
    ,o.name
    FROM sys.objects o
    FOR JSON PATH,INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
  ) AS [data]
FOR JSON PATH;
```

The inner `SELECT` will create an array of objects and call it `"data"`. The outer `SELECT` will put all this together.

The result

```
[  
   {  
      "draw":1,
      "recordsTotal":100,
      "recordsFiltered":10,
      "data":[  
         {  
            "object_id":3,
            "name":"sysrscols"
         },
         {  
            "object_id":5,
            "name":"sysrowsets"
         },
         {  
            "object_id":6,
            "name":"sysclones"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

### Hint

You might want to read about [WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/remove-square-brackets-from-json-without-array-wrapper-option?view=sql-server-201), to control the array brackets...